# Pyglet running multiple windows

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyglet

I have problem when running some test code. There is a lot of code so I will paste only summary of a problem:

```
import pyglet

class Test(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window()

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.window

    def wtf(self):
        self.setUp()
        self.tearDown()
        self.setUp()
        pyglet.app.run()

test = Test()
test.wtf()
```

I would expect upper code to open 1 window, however it opens 2.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Well calling del on a pyglet Window object doesn't shut it down. You need to close it properly in the `tearDown` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyglet

class Test(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.window.close()
        del self.window

    def wtf(self):
        self.setUp()
        self.tearDown()
        self.setUp()
        pyglet.app.run()

test = Test()
test.wtf()
```

You can also use [set_visible](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.window.Window-class.html#set_visible) in order to hide it as a temporary thing if you want to show it later.